# Replace with pattern matching

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

How can I use the `String.Replace` function to use Patterns?

What I would like to do:

```
newTextBox = newTextBox.Replace("<Value> #'a string of any number of chars#' </Value>", 
                                "<Value>" + textBoxName + "</Value>");
```

> #'a string of any number of chars#' can be any string.

Comment: Regular expressions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
newTextBox.Text =
    Regex.Replace(
        newTextBox.Text,
        @"<Value>[^\<]+</Value>",
        "<Value>" + textBoxName.Text + "</Value>");
```

Comment: I would add a short explanation of the regex, and a link to a cheat sheet http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Answer (score 1):

Could also do it like this?:

```
        const string textBoxName = "textBoxName";
        var newTextBox = "<Value>{0}</Value>".Replace("{0}", textBoxName);
```

Comment: why use `string.Replace(...)` and not `string.Format(string format, ...)`?

Comment: @Tobias: True true. String.Format would be better in the case I demonstrated where the elements to be replaced are denoted {0}, {1}, {2} etc or if there's a specific formatting required (Int16 or Float with N number of zeros/decimal places). I guess the .Replace() example I gave would be more suitable if the OP was using placeholders like '#replaceabletext#' or something other than {0}..{N}

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Regex` that's why it exists. [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

With Regex reference:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

And the characters you want to replace: `[0-9a-zA-Z_#' ]`

```
newTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(
    "<Value> #'a string of any number of chars#' </Value>",
    @"<Value>[0-9a-zA-Z_#' ]*</Value>",
    "<Value>" + textBoxName.Text + "</Value>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```